# Is it possible to make an exe file from python that plays music every time the computer boots up?

Tags: python, windows, windows-services

Is there an equivalent python code for the following? Once a person clicks the exe file that I create from a python script, I want the script to create a service that auto starts the script every time the computer boots up, even before anyone has logged in. I want to do something like the following command.

```
C:\Users\Ben>sc create randomfile binPath= "<some exe>" DisplayName= "Random File" start= auto
```

Comment: Why would you create a service to replace the existing task manager service? Just use subprocess to run schtasks.exe or use the task manager's COM interface via win32com or comtypes.

Answer (score 0):

To do that create a .py file
Give it name `service creator.py` or
Or what ever you like.
Then paste this
You can use os.system or subprocess.call. 
Eg:

```
os.system("sc create randomfile binPath= "<some exe>" DisplayName= "Random File" start= auto")
```